# showNotification api not working on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I am using create-react-app v2.

I register my `serviceWorker` in `index.js`:

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

In `App.js` I ask for notification permission:

```
const requestPermission = () => {
  Notification.requestPermission((status) => {
    console.log('Notification permission status', status)
  })
}
```

Once I have the permission of the user (this is working), I want to show a dummy message (this is not working)

```
function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
      if (reg) {
        console.log('navigator', navigator)
        console.log('navigator.serviceWorker', navigator.serviceWorker)
        console.log('reg', reg)
        reg.showNotification('Hello world!');
      } else {
        console.log('no reg', reg)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

My app / component is the standalone from CRA, I am just calling these two functions:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
      if (reg) {
        console.log('navigator', navigator)
        console.log('navigator.serviceWorker', navigator.serviceWorker)
        console.log('reg', reg)
        reg.showNotification('Hello world!');
      } else {
        console.log('no reg', reg)
      }
    })
  }
}

const requestPermission = () => {
  Notification.requestPermission((status) => {
    console.log('Notification permission status', status)
  })
}

function App() {
  requestPermission()
  displayNotification()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I deploy the dummy app on heroku to avoid localhost issue:

https://powerful-mesa-67529.herokuapp.com/

And I can see that my `service-worker` is activated. What surprises me is, that when I inspect the registration object, I don't see the `showNotification` function:

```
// navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg)
```

This is the reg object:

```
ServiceWorkerRegistration {scope: "https://powerful-mesa-67529.herokuapp.com/", updateViaCache: "imports", active: ServiceWorker, installing: null, navigationPreload: NavigationPreloadManager, …}
scope: "https://powerful-mesa-67529.herokuapp.com/"
updateViaCache: "imports"
active: ServiceWorker {scriptURL: "https://powerful-mesa-67529.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js", state: "activated", onerror: null, onstatechange: null}
installing: null
navigationPreload: NavigationPreloadManager {}
sync: SyncManager {}
waiting: null
onupdatefound: ƒ ()
backgroundFetch: BackgroundFetchManager {}
paymentManager: PaymentManager {instruments: PaymentInstruments, userHint: ""}
periodicSync: PeriodicSyncManager {}
pushManager: PushManager {}
__proto__: ServiceWorkerRegistration
```

I am not sure how to debug this, since this is a built-in API and I don't have access. If someone has experience with this topic and can point me why the notification is not working.

My `packageg.json`:

```
{
  "name": "web-pushy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Web apis can be found in Google documentation:

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications